# How to write orWhereYear() in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two datetime columns in my table - from_date and to_date. I need to get records where the year of either from_date or to_date is current year. I am trying to get the records using whereYear and I am stuck at the OR condition

```
$table_records = TableName::whereYear('from_date' , '=', date('Y'))->orWhereYear('to_date' , '=', date('Y'))->orderBy('from_date')->get();
```

But of course there's no orWhereYear in Laravel I guess. Can someone please help me with the query.

Comment: If you are willing to write raw sql, you could get away using

$table_records = DB::select(
"SELECT * from table_name WHERE YEAR(from_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) OR YEAR(to_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) ORDER BY from_date"
);

Note that this is MySQL only

Comment: of course that will surely work but i just want to try if it works by avoiding to make it all a raw query

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way of doing it would be like this:

```
$table_records = TableName::whereYear('from_date' , '=', date('Y'))
    ->whereYear('to_date' , '=', date('Y'), 'or')
    ->orderBy('from_date')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Nice, better than my answer. Didn't notice that 4th parameter in the API. https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereYear

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure with `orWhere()`.

```
TableName::whereYear('from_date','=', date('Y'))
            ->orWhere(function($query) {
                    return $query->whereYear('to_date', '=', [date('Y')]);
             })->get();
```

The resulting parametrized SQL:

```
select * from "table_name" where (extract(year from "from_date") = ? or (extract(year from "to_date") = ?)) and "table_name"."deleted_at" is null
```

Comment: too bad i cannot accept two answers i guess but thanks a lot buddy

Comment: The other answer is better than mine. Still, the closure for orWhere is very useful to know about.

Answer (score 1):

I tried a bit too and came up with this

```
 $table_records = TableName::where(DB::raw("year(from_date)"), '=', date('Y'))
    ->orWhere(DB::raw("year(to_date)"), '=', date('Y'))
    ->orderBy('from_date')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use OrWhereYear, but you could use the 4th parameter of whereyear like so:

```
->whereYear('to_date' , '=', date('Y'), 'or')
```

or, alternatively:

```
->where(function($q){
    $q->whereyear('from_date' , '=', date('Y'))
})->orwhere(function($q){
    $q->whereyear('to_date' , '=', date('Y'))
})
```